# Knockout load variable from AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, knockout.js

I am very new to Knockout and cannot figure out how to do the following:

I want a variable categories to be loaded from AJAX, the AJAX call returns something like:

```
{
    "categories": [
        {
            "slug": "identity",
            "name": "Identity"
        },
        {
            "slug": "buisness-cards",
            "name": "Buisness cards"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to show a `ul` with this like:

```
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;       
    self.categories = [];
    
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "localhost/categories.json",
        success: function(data) {
            self.categories = data; 
        }
    });
   
    console.log(self.categories);
};

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

My HTML is:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: categories">
    <li data-bind="text: $data, css: { selected: $data == "koko" }"></li>
</ul>
```

Obviously I am missing something because categories is used before AJAX call loads it.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of errors in your viewModel and view.

ViewModel:

```
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.categories = ko.observableArray();

    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "localhost/categories.json",
        success: function(data) {
            ko.utils.arrayPushAll(self.categories, data); 
        }
    });
};
```

Html:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: categories">
    <li data-bind="text: name, css: { selected: name == "koko" }"></li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YK34m

Comment: ko.utils.arrayPushAll(self.categories, data) doesnot seem to work. categories is outputed as an empty array

Answer (score 1):

**Javascript**:

```
// 1. Create a JS object
var Slug = function (Slug, Name) {
        self = this;
        self.slug = Slug;
        self.name = Name;
    }

   // 2. Create a mapping, to convert anonymous objects to your new js Slug object
    var mapping = {
        'categories': {
            create: function(options) {
                return new Slug(options.data.slug, options.data.name);
            }
        }
    }

// 3. Make your ajax call here and assign it to the data variable    
var data = {
    "categories": [
        {
            "slug": "identity",
            "name": "Identity"
        },
        {
            "slug": "buisness-cards",
            "name": "Buisness cards"
        }
    ]
};

// 4. Create a view model with the binding using the mapping
function AViewModel()
{
    var self = this;
    self.categories = ko.observableArray();

    $.ajax({
       url:"/echo/json/",
       data:data,
       type:"POST",
       success:function(response)
       {
         self.categories = ko.mapping.fromJS(response, mapping, self);
       }
    });
}

// 5. Apply the bindings
var viewModel = new AViewModel();
```

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

**Html**:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: categories">
      <li data-bind="text: name, css: { selected: name == "koko" }"></li>
    </ul>
```

**JSFiddle**:

With the actual json call mimicked:

http://jsfiddle.net/hutchonoid/TZ3MF/6/

Comment: I replaced var data with ajax call http://jsfiddle.net/gong_planet/5zfm5/ but it now outputs categories undefined

Comment: Give me a minute, just switched laptop off.

Comment: Hi, Check that update out. I've mimicked the json call to show you it working via Fiddler. Please accept the answer if it's working for you. :) I'm favouriting it as I always forget how to do that, that's what took me time.

Comment: got it, it works. But isn't calling ko.mapping.fromJS to restrictive? What if I want another variable to be loaded into viewModel? Wouldn't var viewModel destroy it?

Comment: I prefer it, as adding objects I can do new Slug()....etc rather than anonymous. You can miss out using the mapping and just create anonymous ones instead if you prefer. Then it just maps whatever is in the returned json.

Comment: See this: http://jsfiddle.net/hutchonoid/TZ3MF/4/ It simply maps it without a pre-defined js object, just uses the json.

Comment: Perharps I wasn't clear, sorry. How could I load another variable into viewModel with ajax? I mean, if I again to an $.ajax and var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(response); in success, this will destroy the previous viewModel. Is there a way to add categories to viewModel on ajax success?

Comment: Sorry I am off PC. You basically create an object to contain the objects returned as properties and map them all. If that makes sense. I think it's nested mapping on knockout site by memory, could be wrong mind.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get a chance to finish what you wanted last night. I've refactored it to fit your needs although the other answer is simpler. Here is the updated fiddle with how I map the objects: http://jsfiddle.net/hutchonoid/TZ3MF/6/